How can I make Astro JS bundle all JS into one file?
I am using Astro JS framework but I need to bundle all my component's JavaScript into one single file.
I have this partially working but Astro/Vite/Rollup are also generating entry JS assets for each page, which then subsequently imports this one big JS file.
My astro.config.ts:
export default defineConfig({
  compressHTML: false,
  scopedStyleStrategy: 'where',
  build: {
    format: 'preserve',
    assets: '_assets',
    inlineStylesheets: 'never',
  },
  vite: {
    build: {
      minify: true,
      sourcemap: false,
      cssCodeSplit: false,
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          manualChunks: () => 'app',
          entryFileNames: 'assets/app.[hash].js',
          chunkFileNames: 'assets/app.[hash].js',
          assetFileNames: 'assets/app.[hash].[ext]',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

So every HTML page has its own entry JS file that all link to the same big bundle. I would ideally like to have them all link to the same file and get rid of having their own entry files.
What's produced:

What these entry files all link to:

The reason I need this is because I'm not actually intending to deploy Astro JS itself but to actually build a UI library for my client to launch on from by grabbing the assets. Therefore, code-splitting that Astro provides isn't actually a feature I need.

you probably want to look at https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-entryfilenames (but it's not exactly straightforward)

Yeah, I'm using that already in: chunkFileNames: 'assets/app.[hash].js'. Just cannot figure out how to prevent these individual entry files being created.
